# Filezilla for macOS - Virus?

Tags: virus, antivirus, ftp

I'm trying to download FileZilla for my MacBook and I have McAfee installed. When I click on the download button, the antivirus flags it as Artemis!70506fb398e5 so I decided to upload the file to VirusTotal and I get this:

[image]

Of course I'm downloading it from:
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=osx
(the free version)

Does anyone have any idea if this is a false flag or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download is  shown by many scanners as Adware. The download page you use has a small notice below the download

> This installer **may include bundled offers**. Check below for more options.

Based on this it is likely that the bundled offer is the cause of the warning. If you follow the hint to *check below for more options* you get to [another download page](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1) where a different version is offered. This version does not seem to have the Adware problems.